# How to integrate one function into another using jQuery and promise()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, label, jquery-events

I'm trying to use the `promise()` method in order to integrate one function into another. The following jQuery/ajax currently submits a form in the first section of the code, and then has a second function which tries to **simulate a label click** when a user submits the form.

The label that needs to be click-simulated is:

```
<a href="#contact"><li><label id="contactlink" class="contactbox" for="lightbox-one">Contact</label></li></a>
```

So here's the code:

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#contactform").submit(function(e)
 {    
 e.preventDefault();
    
    // Bind click handler outside of AJAX call
$('label').click(function() {
    var labelID;
    labelID = $(this).attr('for');
    $('#'+labelID).trigger('click');
});

// Make AJAX call
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact-form-handler.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        message: $('#message').val(),
        addy: $('#addy').val(),
        contactsubmit: 'yes'
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log('success');
    $('label').trigger('click');
});
    
});
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine except this second function:

```
.promise().done(function() {            
     $('label').click(function() {
     var labelID;
     labelID = $(this).attr('for');
     $(‘#’+labelID).trigger(‘click’);
                             });
```

Do I combine `.promise().done(function()`  and   `$('label').click(function()`  somehow?  I have no idea how to write this second function properly in order to simulate clicking that label upon form submission. Can you show me what my full code should be? I'm so confused!

**UPDATE:** The label is meant to open this pop-up when clicked:

```
<aside class="lightbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="state" id="lightbox-one" />
  <article class="content">
<h1>Content Here</h1>
  </article>
  <label class="backdrop" for="lightbox-one"></label>
</aside>
```

**Here is the CSS for the pop-up (lightbox):**

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  left:0; top: -3px;
  width: 65px; height: 30px;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.49);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  transition: all .2s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #E4E4E4;
  top: 2px; left: 5px;
}

/* on checked */
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background:rgba(125, 208, 139, 0.62); 
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  background: #ff9a03;
  top: 2px; left: 40px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .ui,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label .ui:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .ui:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label .ui:before {
  content: "no";
  left: 32px
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .ui:after {
  content: "yes";
  color: #ff9a03;
}
[type="checkbox"]:focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dashed #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -1px;
}    

.state{position:absolute;top:0;left:-100vw}
    .state:checked ~ .content{-webkit-transform:none;-ms-transform:none;transform:none;margin-top: 10%;overflow:auto; border-radius: 9px;height:300px;}
    .state:checked ~ .backdrop{bottom:0;opacity:1;z-index:1}
    .lightbox{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;left:0;height:0;padding:0 20px}
    .lightbox .content{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;overflow:hidden;position:relative;z-index:2;max-width:500px;max-height:95vh;margin:20px auto;padding:20px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:translateY(-200%);-ms-transform:translateY(-200%);transform:translateY(-200%);-webkit-transition:.3s -webkit-transform ease-in-out;transition:.3s transform ease-in-out;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}
    .lightbox .header,.lightbox .footer{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-flex-shrink:0;-ms-flex-negative:0;flex-shrink:0;-webkit-box-align:center;-webkit-align-items:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}
    .lightbox .header .h,.lightbox .footer .h{margin:0}
    .lightbox .header .button:not(:first-child),.lightbox .footer .button:not(:first-child){margin-left:auto}
    .lightbox .header{padding-bottom:10px}
    .lightbox .footer{padding-top:20px}
    .lightbox .main{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1}
    .lightbox .backdrop{position:fixed;z-index:-1;top:0;right:0;bottom:100%;left:0;opacity:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);-webkit-transition:.3s opacity ease-in-out;transition:.3s opacity ease-in-out}
```

Comment: Um, this functionality is built-into browsers already (that label clicks trigger the `for`-referenced input), not sure why you want to replicate this?

Comment: I'm quite sure that you do not want to bind your `click` handlers inside the `submit` handler, or inside the ajax callback.

Comment: I have no idea what best practice is here. I simply need the form to submit and to also open the pop-up window via simulating clicking the label I posted. Any solution you can offer is gold at this point.

Comment: I think you don't want to bind any handler at all - you just want to call `$('label').trigger('click');`? Maybe you should detail how a click opens the pop-up, there might be a better way than simulating a click.

Comment: I'm not sure how a click opens the pop-up, isn't the evident by the code I provided? It's wrapped in <a> tags but I believe it's the "for=..." function that makes it open the pop-up.   I'm brand new to jQuery so am not sure if I should just call '$('label').trigger('click');' . I only know that I need the pop-up to open after the form has successfully submitted. Sorry I'm not a bigger help, I feel stuck

Comment: No, a popup doesn't open on its own. There must be some code in your page that is responsible for that. My guess it that is has something to do with that `lightbox` class?

Comment: Oh maybe! I've added the lightbox's CSS to the question. There are no scripts associated with the lightbox opening though...

Comment: Ah. No need to trigger clicks on the label then. Just set `.checked` value of the `#lightbox-one` checkbox.

Comment: Thank you!!! Solved. What a simple solution... oh  man. I ended up using $('#lightbox-one').prop('checked', true);  in my success function. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

With the guidance of Bergi, I was able to solve this problem by adding this code to my success handler:  `$('#lightbox-one').prop('checked', true);`

The entire code now looks like:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#contactform").submit(function(e)
 {
          e.preventDefault();
        if ($.trim($("#message").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#addy").val()) === "") 
           {
         return false;
           }
           var value = document.getElementById('message').value;
            if (value.length < 10) {
            return false; 
                                   }
          $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "contact-form-handler.php",
                  dataType:"text",
                  data: {message: $('#message').val(), addy: $('#addy').val(), contactsubmit: 'yes'},

                  success: function()   
             {
                $('#lightbox-one').prop('checked', true); 
             }
                })

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$.ajax()` method automatically returns a promise—it is native to the function. Also, since you're using `.done()`, you should no longer use the deprecated `.success()` callback. There is no need to chain `.promise().done()`.

With regards to the click event binding, you should **do it outside the AJAX call**, otherwise you will bind **multiple** click event handlers to the `<label>` for every single successful call. Therefore, you should bind the event handler *outside* the AJAX call, and then simply use `.trigger()` to trigger the click event when the AJAX call.

You have not provided the context in which `<label>` element you are targeting though...

```
// Bind click handler outside of AJAX call
$('label').click(function() {
    var labelID;
    labelID = $(this).attr('for');
    $('#'+labelID).trigger('click');
});

// Make AJAX call
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact-form-handler.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        message: $('#message').val(),
        addy: $('#addy').val(),
        contactsubmit: 'yes'
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log('success');
    $('label').trigger('click');
});
```

Also, I don't know if this is intentional or not, but you are using smart quotes (`‘` and `’`) for the last line in your `.done()` function. You should use dumb quotes `'` instead.

Comment: Wow, thanks Terry! I'll try it now. As for the context of the <label> element, it's main purpose is to open a pop-up window when a user clicks it. The pop-up isn't a modal, but instead is placed within <aside> tags. I've updated my question to include this pop-up's code. This label is the only label on the entire page. Hopefully your code still applies.

Comment: If it is the **only** `<label>` element, it should work. Give it a try, and if doesn't work let me know :)

Comment: It successfully submits the form with details, but won't open the pop-up. I assumed that I was suppose to nest your code between  $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#contactform").submit(function(e)   otherwise it wouldn't know to launch upon form submission. I have updated my question's code to reflect the latest changes. Why won't it open the pop-up? Perhaps it should simulate a 'check' not a 'click'? Since input type is a checkbox. Thank you

Comment: That is true. You should place it within the submit event handler.

Comment: So you're saying the updated code in my question is correct? It does not seem to open the pop-up though. What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks anyway Terry but Bergi helped me solve it simple by adding this code to my success handler:  $('#lightbox-one').prop('checked', true);

Comment: Then just move it to the `.done()` handler. The `.success()` handler has been deprecated some time ago.

Comment: You're right. But my code has    `success: function()  {`  not `.success()`.  How do I replace `success:function(){`  with done instead? Can you show me? Thanks!

Comment: You simply chain `.done()` to the `$.ajax()` method like in my answer. The `success` object in the function *is* the `jqXHR.success()` method.